# What is a good method of creating a pivot point between flat metal bars?

Tags: robotics, joining

I could use a hand choosing the mechanism for joining the ends of 2 flat metal bars (each around 3/4" wide and 1/8" thick) so that they pivot freely but without play.

What I'm currently planning is to drill a 1/8" hole in one and a 1/4" hole in the other, put a 1/8" diameter rivet through the bar with the 1/8" hole, then a thin plastic (Teflon maybe) washer, put a Teflon plain sleeve bearing (looks like a tiny 1/8" long pipe with a .126" I.D. and a 1/4" O.D.) into the 1/4" hole, pass the rivet through that, then through another thin plastic washer, a thin metal washer, and then close the rivet.

I think it's important to avoid metal-on-metal contact, but I'm not certain about that.  Is there a simpler design that I could use?

Comment: What are the dimensional tolerances on your metal, your machining tolerance capabilities, and how much radial motion qualifies as "no play"? You could just use a [shoulder screw](http://www.mcmaster.com/#shoulder-screws/=10hi5yk) with a shoulder length slightly longer than the combined width of your parts installed in a plain through hole.

Comment: I was thinking it would be best to avoid metal-to-metal rubbing, which I would have if the shoulder screw simply passes into holes in the bars.  I suppose I could use a shoulder screw with a Teflon bushing, to separate the shaft of the screw from the inside of the hole in the bars.  This is a joint that's going to do a lot of motion.

Comment: Metal-to-metal rubbing is how most bearings work, like roller chain in a bicycle, or crankshaft bearings in a car. Like those bearings, you just need to remember to lubricate them as often as your load and use cycles require; typically just often enough as is required to maintain a lubricating film. If you never want to lubricate the joint then PTFE bushings will work, and you can also get oil impregnated bronze bushings. Just a matter of cost now vs. cost in the future (maintenance).

Comment: Its not metal-to-metal rubbing you want to avoid, its to not  have the same type of metal in contact with itself that is critical. Hence bronze/steel, steel/cast-iron, aluminum/steel all will work. Assuming that this is a robot arm that will see less then 10,000 cycles of movement, the teflon is probably overkill.

Comment: @Mhz4.77: Thank you.  Excuse my ignorance, but what's the risk with contact between the same metals?  And does that also apply to similar metals (such as different alloys of aluminum)?

Comment: See also this related question: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22/what-method-can-i-use-to-make-a-pivot-point-in-an-aluminum-linkage

Answer (score 1):

Thrust bearings and thrust washers are made for this exact purpose.   Your design intent is pretty close to that of a thrust bearing but more complex.

Comment: I assumed that, in the way I'm planning to use the Teflon washer between the 2 bars, that washer would serve as a thrust washer.  I was actually looking at thrust bearings first, but a Teflon washer looks like it'll accomplish the same result, at a lower cost.

Comment: Makes sense.  You can find flanged bearings, too, that might let you eliminate the rivets.

Comment: How would a flanged bearing let me eliminate the rivets?

Answer (score 1):

Use a 1/4" dia x 3/16" long shoulder screw with 1/16" thick washer. Also use nut and washer on the thread. You can get the screw at: http://www.mcmaster.com/#90298a530/=10jcicb
A steel shoulder screw will be much stronger than a rivet and teflon (plastic) bearings. Steel on steel is commonly used in pivots from door hinges to motorcycle chains.